# How to Overlay Loading View for XAMARIN.FORMS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How to use overlay Activity indicator when select any list view.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"

        ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected">
     <ListView.Header>
         <Label Text="Store Allocation" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

     </ListView.Header>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}"  Height="200" Detail="{Binding Detail}" DetailColor="Black" TextColor="Red"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you are not using MVVM (does not look like) and you are on a `Page` it's fairly easy

Put an `ActivityIndicator` as well as the `ListView` in an `AbsoluteLayout`

```
<ContentPage x:Name="Page" ...>
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <ListView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <!-- ... -->
        </ListView>
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Source={x:Reference Page}}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,-1,-1" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I've added an `AbsoluteLayout` wrapping your `ListView`. The `ListView` is set up to take the whole area of the `AbsoluteLayout`. Furthermore I've added an `ActivityIndicator` on top, that is centered and has its default size (`AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"` and `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,-1,-1"`).

As you can see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Page/#Public_Properties), `Page` exposes the `IsBusy` property, which you can set, when the page is busy, i.e. retrieving data or whatever. I've bound the `IsRunning` property of the `ActivityIndicator` to `IsBusy`, that the `ActivityIndicator` shows up whenever the `Page` indicates that it's busy.

From your code-behind, set `IsBusy` for example from an `async` method that retrieves your data

```
private async void Update()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    this.Data = await GetData();
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you wanted to know, how to disable the `ListView` in the background:

You could overlay a tranparent `BoxView`

```
<BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    InputTransparent="false"
    IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Source={x:Reference Page}}" />
```

Put this between your `ListView` and your `ActivityIndicator` and it should intercept all events the `ListView` would receive otherwise. Is is shown only when the `ActivityIndicator` is shown.

Comment: async void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, 
  SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
          {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            string Id = e.SelectedItem.ToString();
                     
            var query = SBObj.GetStoreMasterDetail(Convert.ToInt32(Id));

Comment: I have applied your code but after click on list item activity  indication doesn't show

Comment: After multiple click the activity indicator has been shown but background list still clickable and user can click multi times, How to disable background listview