# How to Xamarin.forms Scroll work with AbsoluteLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this .XAML page and Scroll doesn't work
Its working fine when I have remove AbsoluteLayout and take stacklayout.

```
<ScrollView>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
       ItemSelected="lstView_ItemSelected">

            <ListView.Header>
                <Label Text="Store Allocation" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  />

            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}"  Height="200" Detail="{Binding Detail}" DetailColor="Black" TextColor="Red"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Opacity="0.7" InputTransparent="False" IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Source={x:Reference Page}}" />
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Source={x:Reference Page}}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,-1,-1" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your XAML basically *"says"* put a `ScrollView` on the page, with an `AbsoluteLayout` filling that `ScrollView`. Since the inner layout perfectly fits the `ScrollView` there is no need to scroll. Moreover the `ListView` and the `BoxView` are set to take the whole `AbsoluteLayout` (`AbsoluteLayout.LAyoutBounds="0,0,1,1"`), no more no less. Why *should* the `ScrollView` scroll?

Furthermore, *if* it worked that way, you'd scroll the `ActivityIndicator` with everything else, which is supposedly not what you want. I'd assume that you'd like to keep the `ActivityIndicator` in place, on top of the `ListView`.

What you could try (I'm not 100% sure, but it should work) is wrapping the `ListView` only with the `ScrollView` and put the `ScrollView` in the `AbsoluteLayout` this way, the `ScrollView` will recognize the `ListView` being too large for the screen and enable scrolling, while everything else stays in place:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <ListView x:Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            ItemSelected="lstView_ItemSelected">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Label Text="Store Allocation" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  />
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}"  Height="200" Detail="{Binding Detail}" DetailColor="Black" TextColor="Red"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
    <BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Opacity="0.7" InputTransparent="False" IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Source={x:Reference Page}}" />
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Source={x:Reference Page}}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,-1,-1" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: I want to Overlay loading view, Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985304/how-to-overlay-loading-view-for-xamarin-forms

Comment: I know. I was the one giving the answer to your other question. What is the exact issue about the answer given here? I did not remove the `ActivityIndicator` overlay, I just moved the `ScrollView` down the hierarchy, that it wraps the `ListView` directly and not the whole `AbsoluteLayout`, which does not work for the reasons I gave in my answer.

Comment: Problem is, When I have used AbsoluteLayout under scrollView then ScrollView doesn't work.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I said. Therefor I told you to put the `ScrollView` *in* the `AbsoluteLayout` and not the other way.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for help

Comment: When I have used above code then Scroll works only Vertically and getting issue with Horizontal

Comment: What are you trying to scroll vertically?

Comment: I am simple copy paste your code, and When change device orientation to Horizonatal the scroll not working.
Scroll work both Vertical and Horizontal if I have used NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False". But If true then only work when device is Vertical mode

Comment: I'll see if I can check it during my break.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually set the height of your AbsoluteLayout.

```
<ScrollView>
<AbsoluteLayout HeightRequest="800">
      <!--Page Contents-->
</AbsoluteLayout>
</ScrollView>
```