# Xamarin - How to add a custom small pop up on each item image click on collectionView in Android & iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a collection view, which will displays the list of items. In each item, i have a image button, on clicking on that image button I need to display a control,which display something like below image(a small pop up kind or custom toolbar item control which list few items for me to select on each item click), also looking for the co-ordinates should map with where the user clicked.

[image]

Is there any way we can implement the control on xamarin in collection view?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to implement what you have in mind by using an `AbsoluteLayout`. You can take inspiration from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985304/how-to-overlay-loading-view-for-xamarin-forms), which implements an overlay that displays an `ActivityIndicator` for loading. Instead of the ActivityIndicator, you can create a `StackLayout` with the fields *Properties*, *Add to Favorites*, and *Share*, and [set the coordinates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout#position-and-size-children) of the StackLayout to those of the point clicked by the user.